# filtering data in datagridview using combobox and button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, filtering

I want to filter data in datagridview using combobox and button. I been searching for hours already and tried some codes but I always got an error.

I would be thankful if someone could tell me the best and easy way on how to code.

Here is a picture of the form

[image: Form]

I want to filter the data in the datagridview by selecting either year level or section name and clicking the button `Show`. By doing so the data that is left in datagridview should only be data with the chosen year level or section name.
I'm trying to use this code now but its neither giving me result nor error

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource show = new BindingSource();
    datagridview1.DataSource = show;
    show.Filter = "ColLevel ='"+cmbYearLevelF.Text+"' OR ColSectionNumber ='"+cmbSectionNameF.Text+"'";
}
```

Comment: You must first set the DataSource of the BindingSource. To filter, strings are enclosed in apostrophes  and numerics no apostrophes. So if ColLevel is a int then use "ColLevel = " + cmbYearLevelF.Text etc.

Comment: The form in the picture - how is grid populated with the data that we see?

Comment: @IvanStoev there is a create button which call another form with text fields to fill up and put the data to the datagridview

Comment: In other words, you don't have initially some sort of a data source bound to the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the filter on the *existing* BindingSource, like this:

```
existingBindingSource.Filter = "ColLevel = '2'";
```

Hard code a simple value first to make sure it is working.

By *existing* I mean the BindingSource that is currently attached to the DataGridView.

Comment: it's not working. maybe there is something missing in declaring the binding source code but i don't know what is it.

Comment: The BindingSource object should already exist...or you wouldn't see any data.  It should already be declared and instantiated.